# Enums in LabVIEW

Tags: enums, labview

I have an enum with around 200 elements in labVIEW. Some elements inbetween are placeholder1, placeholder2, placeholder3 and so on, which really have no value in real. But labVIEW has a zero in array in place of nothing. I want to get all the indexes of these place-holders programmatically and want to know if that is possible. Since zero is present there, it is causing problems with other calculations. So I want them to exist but delete all of them only when I am doing calculations.

These are basically linked to another array, So I want to get the index of this placeholder%d and delete the data from the array from those indices. Been trying for a while and not able to get a solution, can someone help?

I have tried different methods but none of those were working. So I will try any new solution that I find here. I dont know how to deal with enums programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use property node. To create property node explicitly, you will need to place your enum as control on the VI's front panel, and then right-click -> Create -> Property Node -> Strings. Or, access property node via reference.

Use `Strings` array to iterate over it, and search for "placeholder..." strings.

[image]

Please refer to this [knowledge base article](https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA03q000000YGxDCAW).

Answer (score 2):

kosist's answer is the right idea, but using a property node to get the enum strings has a big downside: it forces the front panel to load into memory, which makes the VI run slower. The following is a way to get the enum strings without using a property node. (Note: Coercing max i32 to the enum type is a way to get the last value of the enum even if the enum is edited to add more elements.)
[image: block diagram]